# Ordering Django queryset by a @property

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to order a query set by a property I defined in the model, but not sure the best way to do this. Here's the property:

```
@property
def name(self):
    if self.custom_name:
        return self.custom_name
    else:
        return self.module_object.name
```

Essentially, I'd like to do a:

```
things = Thing.objects.all().order_by('-name')
```

but of course getting a Caught FieldError while rendering: Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field.

Any ideas?

**EDIT: I understand that I can't sort this way because the `@property` isn't a database field. My question is how to sort given that `@property` isn't a database field.**

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can't do that because that property is not in MySQL, but in your python code. If you really want to do this, you can on the client-side(though it will be very slow):

```
sorted(Thing.objects.all(), key=lambda t: t.name)
```

Comment: This is almost working, but it's returning odd sorting. Basically, the ones with self.custom_name are sorted and then the ones with self.module_object.name are sorted next.

Comment: nevermind. I just needed to add a .lower() after the name for the case-insensitive sort

Answer (score 4):

`order_by` happens on the sql level, so it can't make use of properties, only field data.

have a look at the [queryset api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra), you may be able to make use of e.g. `extra` to annotate your query and sort on that

Comment: thanks .. I've taken a look at Extra but not sure how to incorporate the @property into it

Comment: @brenden, you don't incorporate the property as such. In my example, I needed to have status=DRAFT (where DRAFT='draft') come first. So, I used extra to insert a draft column in the select statement that was true if status=DRAFT (exluding status=DONE) and ordered on it like so: MyModel.objects.exclude(status=DONE).extra(select={'draft': 'status = %s'}, select_params=[DRAFT]).order_by('-draft')

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [django-denorm](http://initcrash.github.com/django-denorm/tutorial.html). It lets you maintain calculated values in the database (which you can then use to sort efficiently) for the cost of a single method decorator.

Answer (score 3):

You can only order by database fields. You can pull all records, turn them into a list, and sort them, although that may be inefficient and slow.

Or you can add a database field called `name` and fill it in via a post-save hook; then you can sort it using `order_by`.