# Order queryset by JSON field of latest FK

Tags: python, django

I have such models:

```
class Configuration(models.Model):
    @property
    def latest_value_A(self):
        return self.result_set.latest("created_time").data.get("value_A")

class Result(models.Model):
    data = models.JSONField()  # "value_A" key is present in JSON
    configuration = models.ForeignKey(Configuration, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to do something like `Configuration.objects.order_by("latest_value_A")` which obviously fails cause it's just a property and not stored in DB. But what would be the proper way of doing it?

UPDATE: I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: Do you use a PostgreSQL database?

Comment: Yep, I use PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **sorted** function from python. Something like:

```
sorted(Configuration.objects.all(), key=lambda t: t.latest_value_A)
```

A reference if needed:
[Ordering Django queryset by a @property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478494/ordering-django-queryset-by-a-property)

Comment: Nice solution! Solved my problem easily, I'm wondering on it's efficiency, tho.