# How do update last message date in Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models where users create a post and comment on that post. When users comment this post I want updating last_message date on UserPost model. If there are no comments yet I want the default last_message date to be set to the date the post was created.

**Models:**

```
class UserPosts(models.Model):
   postTitle = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Title")
   postContent = RichTextField(null=True, verbose_name="Content")
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(
                auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Date of upload")
   last_message = ?????????????????

   def __str__(self):
       return self.postTitle



class UserMessages(models.Model):
    postMessages = RichTextField(null=True, verbose_name="Message")
    post = models.ForeignKey(
             UserPosts, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Linked Post", null=True)
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Date of upload")
```

**EDİT**

MY VİEWS:

```
def forums(request,forumname):
   forum = Category.objects.get(categoryName=forumname)
   post2 = UserPosts.objects.all().filter(category=forum.id).order_by("- 
                     usermessages").filter(category=forum.id)
   context = {
      'posts': post2,
   }
   return render(request, "_forums.html",context)
```

MY TEMPLATE:

```
    {% for post in posts %}
       <div class="mb-2 text-muted">
           {{post.last_message | naturaltime}}
       </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

I couldn't find anything relevant to this topic in the Django docs, Google, and other sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an option to not have it at the database, you can just calculate this at the time when you need it. So for that you can use a model property:

```py
class UserPosts(models.Model):
    postTitle = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Title")
    postContent = RichTextField(null=True, verbose_name="Content")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Date of upload")
    
    @property
    def last_message(self):
        last_message = self.usermessages_set.order_by('-created_at').first()
        if last_message:
            return last_message.created_at
        return self.created_at
```

So if a post doesn't have a message yet, it will get it's own `created_at` field. You can then use this like a property:

```
post = UserPosts.objects.first()
print(post.last_message)
```

Also consider using [`cached_property`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property) if you plan to use this field in a view multiple times.

Comment: thank you sir its working but there is a problem.  When trying to display posts in my template file, they are not sorted by last message date and another thing I was wondering is that you used the usermessages_set object in the last_message function. What does this mean? I am editing my views file and html file to help you. thanks

Comment: It's the backward relationship that allows you to access the reverse of the foreign key (userposts -> usermessages). You can find the explanation and some examples [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

Comment: For ordering, it's a little bit tricky because you case depends on a multi-valued field. Try to read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) first especially the first note.

Comment: Otherwise you can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8478586/6759844)