# How to order the results by two columns using admin.display decorator

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-orm

Please consider the following example:

```
# models.py

class Case(models.Model):
    number = models.SmallIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    year = models.SmallIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    ...
```

```
#admin.py
@admin.register(Case)
class CaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['case_number', ...]
    ordering = ['-year', '-number']

    @admin.display(ordering=['-year', '-number'])
    def case_number(self, case):
        return f'{case.number} / {case.year}'
```

Now how can I specify the order to be by `'-year'` and `'-number'` using the `admin.display()` decorator?

If it can not be done with the `admin.display()` decorator, is there another way to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like this is not (yet) implemented. Will look to wrap this into a PR since this is indeed something that seems missing.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for letting me know it's missing, and for your willing to implement it. 

Comment: can you share the *full* traceback (not only the error message) when using a property?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, sure: here it is: https://paste.debian.net/plain/1282357

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [@Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) for the [patch](https://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/34646/django_ordering.py.diff) you provided in order to make this possible.

Even thought the developers didn't agree to implement it. Thank you for the time you spent patching it and opening the [#34646](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/34646) ticket.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible but it's a very slow link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8478586/19205926)

Django **`order_by()`** query method order records using model field

##### Here I added an alternative way for it. using **`save()`** method overriding please check here...

## models.py

```
class Case(models.Model):
    number = models.SmallIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    year = models.SmallIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    case_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.case_number = int(f"{self.number}{self.year}")
        super(Case, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

## admin.py

```
@admin.register(Case)
class CaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("case_number", "year", "number", "id")[::-1]
    ordering = ['-case_number']
```

## Browser Output

[image]

##### NOTE - here you need to add one extra field for saving **`case_number`** but, it's a better way to order records using **`case_number`**

Comment: Nice trick, although the data will be redundant.. yet it's better than the given link.

Comment: I do like it, but I don't think it's ideal because of the data redundant. (which I don't want & need in db). So, I'll wait till ordering by multi fields are implemented/supported in the `admin.display` decorator.